# Capacitor - debugging basic LED?

Tags: capacitor

I am trying to experiment with capacitor. Basically, here I am trying to replace the battery source with the capacitor when the switch is turned off.
However, my circuit doesn't illuminate the LED1. What basics I am missing here.
Is capacitor won't be charged here when the 5v is supplied. Once the switch is off shouldn't it give the power to the LED1.

[image]

Comment: Are you allowing for the fact that it won't be on for very long? Try changing R3 to 10k and it might last a second (but won't be very bright).

Comment: You put the switch in the wrong place. It should be at marker '3' on your schematic. And Q1 must stay ON. You need a master switch at the battery to turn it all off.

Comment: The capacitor can only charge when the led is on. It doesn't charge enough to light the led.

Comment: Further C1 will not be charged to more than the LED's forward voltage if it's in parallel

Comment: Put the capacitor between "5" and ground.

Comment: @Andyaka Or connect "3" with "5" or "1" to "0", what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that the capacitor can only charge up to the LED forward voltage. If LED1 is a red LED then it will have a V<sub>F</sub> (forward voltage) of 1.8 to 2.0 V and that is the voltage you will see on C1. (You should be able to measure this.) Now when you switch off Q1 you have only just enough voltage to light the LED for a very short while before the voltage drops below the LED visible range.

Wire C1 between 3 and 1 and leave out R3. You can get a very rough idea of the discharge time from the time constant \$ \tau = R_1 C_1 = 1k \times 400\mu = 0.4 \ \text s \$.

Comment: can I use 1000micro farad capacitor here? Is it safe to use it? Can it burn ?